# On an asymptotic integral decay

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, integration, asymptotics, integral-transforms

Let $f\in C^{\infty}([-1,0])$ be real-valued and suppose that

$$ \left| \int_{-1}^{0} f(t)\,e^{\lambda t} \,{\rm d} t \right| \leq e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}},$$

for all $\lambda > 0$. Does it follow that $f(t)$ is zero on $-\epsilon \leq t\leq 0$, for some $\epsilon>0$?

My hunch is that this is actually not true but fail to come up with a counter example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll change $[-1,0]$ to $[0,1]$ (so $t\to -t$), which seems easier on the brain.

$f(t)=e^{-1/t}$ is a counterexample: For $0<t<1/\sqrt{\lambda}$, we have $f\le e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}}$, so this part of the integral satisfies the desired bound, and if $t>1/\sqrt{\lambda}$, then $e^{-\lambda t}\le e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}}$.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be in line with the fact that $f(t)=e^{-\frac{1}{t}}$ belongs to Gevrey class $G^{2}$ which have Fourier transforms with exponential decay rate $e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}}$. I wonder if this can be proved that any $f$ satisfying the decay rate in question must therefore be in $G^{2}$.